# Global CSS selectors for Laravel Dusk tests

Tags: laravel, selenium, laravel-dusk

I am using `Laravel Dusk` to write `Selenium` tests for my project.
I have a class called `PrivilegeLevelsTest` in my `tests\Browser` folder.

I am using in that class a lot of complex selectors like `->type('.gen-search-table[data-uri="table/userSearch"] input', $this->lettersToSearch)`

I've seen in the documentation that these selectors can be declared at the `Page` class, in the `siteElements` method, but these declarations can only be seen from the `Pages` folder. Since I don't want to put my test there, I am asking if there is an alternative method to see these declarations from the outside?

My `Page.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser\Pages;

use Laravel\Dusk\Page as BasePage;

abstract class Page extends BasePage
{
 /**
 * Get the global element shortcuts for the site.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function siteElements()
{
    return [
        '@element' => '#selector',
        '@search' => '.gen-search-table[data-uri="table/userSearch"] input'
    ];
}
}
```

And I want to use `@search` like this:

```
     public function testAdminCanListUsers()
     {
     $this->browse(function(Browser $browser) {
        $browser->loginAs($this->user)
            ->visit('/profile')
            ->pause(3000)
            ->type('@search', $this->lettersToSearch)
            ->pause(3000)
            ->press('Show All')
            ->assertSee($this->userToSearch->user_name);
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own `Page` class:

```php
class MyPage extends Page {

}
```

Then use it with `on()`:

```php
$browser->loginAs($this->user)
    ->visit('/profile')
    ->pause(3000)
    ->on(new MyPage)
    ->type('@search', $this->lettersToSearch)
    ->pause(3000)
    ->press('Show All')
    ->assertSee($this->userToSearch->user_name);
```